# Postgresql Updating Non-Labeled View Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I accidentally created a view with a concatenated column and did not alias the column on creation. I would like to fix the alias, but I'm not sure how to alter the view's column since the anonymous reference is not working. Is there a proper way to alter the views column name?

Query to create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW emp_full_name AS
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
    FROM employee
```

Querying the view:

```
?column?
John Doe
Jane Doe
....
```

Attempt to update column with new name:

```
ALTER VIEW emp_full_name RENAME ?column? TO full_name
```

Error:

```
LINE 1: ALTER VIEW emp_full_name RENAME ?column? TO full_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the entire view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_full_name as
    SELECT (first_name || ' ' || last_name) as full_name
    FROM employee;
```

Comment: I ran your query above and received the following error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 1: ALTER VIEW emp_full_name AS`

Comment: @cphill . . . `as` is not used for `alter view`.  It is used for `create view`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for catching that. Still seeing an error with the edited answer `ERROR: 
 syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 2:     SELECT (first_name || ' ' || last_name) as full_name`